# How to combine SQL query for getting total records and getting records for pagination limit

Tags: php, mysql

I have to apply two queries for pagination.

1) Select all records.

2) Select records with limit.

As per example

```
$total_records = 'select * from table_name';

$for_pagination = 'select * from table_name limit 10, 2';
```

Is there any solution or way to get limit records and all records together with single query?

Comment: No you have to run multiple queries

Comment: If you already have all records, why would you need to run a second query?  Note that using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is fairly meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use Union All? if they have the same number of columns and data type.

https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/union_all.php

Otherwise, could you please provide further information (such as sample data) as we don't have much idea on your request based on information from your question.